# Is second principle of thermodynamics translatable as a probability diffusion equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, information, diffusion

The general diffusion equation examples thereof are heat equation and Fick law says the flow of a given extensive quantity like thermal energy or mass is proportionnal to the gradient of a related intensive quantity like temperature or concentration.
Can the increasing of entropy be viewed asathe existence of an "entropic flow" proportional to a gradient of probability ? Indeed an isolated system evolves so as to uniformize the distribution of probability of microstates compatible with the observed microstate.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy "generation" in irreversible processes can be viewed as being proportional to the square of concentration gradients, temperature gradients, and velocity gradients.  But, in addition to entropy generation, there is also the usual entropy flux, determined by the heat flux divided by the absolute temperature.  For lots of discussion and details on this, see Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, Chapter 11, Problem 11D.1.